# if statement to one line with return

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I know that the 'one line if  statement' question has been asked multiple times already but I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code. I want to convert

```
def has_no_e(word):
    if 'e' not in word:
        return True
```

to a one line function like:

```
def hasNoE(word):
    return True if 'e' not in word
```

but I get a Syntax Error if  I do so -why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think because you do not specify the `else` part. You should write it as:

```
return True if 'e' not in word else None
```

This is because Python sees it as:

```
return <expr>
```

and you specify a *ternary condition operator* as `<expr>` which has syntax:

```
<expr1> if <condition> else <expr2>
```

So Python is looking for your `else` part.

---

## Return `False`?

Perhaps you want to return `False` in case the test fails. In that case you could thus write it like:

```
return True if 'e' not in word else False
```

but this can be shortened in:

```
return 'e' not in word
```

Comment: Thanks, man. The missing else part was the issue

Answer (score 2):

Ternary conditional statements require you to have an `else` in them as well. Thus, you must have:

```
def hasNoE(word):
    return True if 'e' not in word else False
```